# Linux Server hacked?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, hacking, moodle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

I'm trying to determine if this linex webserver/openfire server has been compromised by some form of malware or a hacker. Can you please help me determine if this server has been hacked?

The snippet of logs below are from the linux server running apache. A few days ago the moodle site, which is installed on the server, started to render the apache default page. Also the access logs show some activity im not sure of. Please see logs below.

```
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:13:31:01 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:13:31:01 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
99.41.69.92 - - [02/Apr/2012:13:33:35 -0600] "GET /files/externallibs.php HTTP/1.1" 404 306 "-" "curl/7.18.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.18.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.1"
212.34.151.92 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:01:46 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 305 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.01 [en]"
212.34.151.92 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:01:46 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 305 "http://173.164.35.181/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php\r" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.01 [en]"
82.223.140.4 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:05:03 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 305 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.01 [en]"
82.223.140.4 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:05:04 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 305 "_http://173.164.35.181/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php\r" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.1) Opera 7.01 [en]"
10.0.0.100 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:25:35 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 5043 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110330 CentOS/3.6-1.el5.centos Firefox/3.6.15"
10.0.0.100 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:25:38 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 295 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110330 CentOS/3.6-1.el5.centos Firefox/3.6.15"
50.17.41.60 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:27:29 -0600] "HEAD /icons/apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; NetcraftSurveyAgent/1.0; +info@netcraft.com)"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:42:33 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:42:33 -0600] "POST _http://vlad-tepes.bofh.it/freenode-proxy-checker.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 307 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:42:33 -0600] "GET _http://vlad-tepes.bofh.it/freenode-proxy-checker.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 307 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:14:42:36 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:03:48 -0600] "POST _http://vlad-tepes.bofh.it/freenode-proxy-checker.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 307 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:03:48 -0600] "GET _http://vlad-tepes.bofh.it/freenode-proxy-checker.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 307 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:03:48 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:03:48 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
66.233.63.54 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:12:19 -0600] "GET /files/externallibs.php HTTP/1.1" 404 306 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"
70.114.161.135 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:17:12 -0600] "GET /files/externallibs.php HTTP/1.1" 404 306 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"
99.41.69.231 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:52:21 -0600] "GET /files/externallibs.php HTTP/1.1" 404 306 "-" "curl/7.18.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.18.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.1"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:55:40 -0600] "GET _http://vlad-tepes.bofh.it/freenode-proxy-checker.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 307 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:55:40 -0600] "POST _http://vlad-tepes.bofh.it/freenode-proxy-checker.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 307 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:55:40 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:15:55:40 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
10.0.0.253 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:01:45 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 5043 "-" "WWW-Mechanize/1.0.0 (http://rubyforge.org/projects/mechanize/)"
10.0.0.253 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:02:27 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 5043 "-" "WWW-Mechanize/1.0.0 (http://rubyforge.org/projects/mechanize/)"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:13:40 -0600] "POST _http://vlad-tepes.bofh.it/freenode-proxy-checker.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 307 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:13:40 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:13:40 -0600] "GET _http://vlad-tepes.bofh.it/freenode-proxy-checker.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 307 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:13:40 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
89.135.124.125 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:20:47 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 305 "_http://173.164.35.181/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php" "Opera"
89.135.124.125 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:20:48 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 305 "_http://173.164.35.181/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php" "Opera"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:29:59 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:29:59 -0600] "GET http://vlad-tepes.bofh.it/freenode-proxy-checker.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 307 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:29:59 -0600] "CONNECT 213.92.8.7:31204 HTTP/1.0" 405 303 "-" "-"
85.190.0.3 - - [02/Apr/2012:16:29:59 -0600] "POST http://vlad-tepes.bofh.it/freenode-proxy-checker.txt HTTP/1.0" 404 307 "-" "-"
```

Answer (score 9):

The log snippet shows a lot of *scanning activity* to see if your web-server will act as an open proxy. They're failing (all of those 403, 404, and 405 results) so that's good.

Scanning activity is normal background noise. Scanning activity that's finding stuff isn't.